# Linux - autocomplete prompting db password

Tags: linux, database, autocomplete, passwords

As you know when you execute queries like that one:

```
cat query.sql | mysql -u foo -p bar
```

Then you are prompted to insert database password. Is there a way to autocomplete this step instead of typing the password every time you want to execute a query?

Answer (score 0):

You can create `.my.cnf` option file in your `home` directory like the following one.

```
[client]
user=foo
password=bar
```

Most MySQL programs can read startup options from option files. More info [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html)